# roxygen2 not fully updating DESCRIPTION file

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm making my first package `rlandscape`, using Roxygen2 and trying to follow the plain  Roxygen vignette since Roxygen2 doesn't have one.

As in [the vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen/vignettes/roxygen.pdf) (page 3), I created a file called `rlandscape-package.R` that contains nothing but package documentation. In the vignette, they say

> each Roxygen description block must be followed by a statement, even
>   header material that describes a le or package in lieu of a specific
>   function. roxygen() is provided as a NOOP (null statement) to stand in
>   for such cases.

but if I follow the description block with `roxygen()` a call to `package.skeleton` produces `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "roxygen"`. So I've tried leaving the `roxygen()` call out entirely as well as replacing it with `NA`, both of which seem to produce the same results: `package.skeleton()` works successfully (including `rlandscape-package.R` as one of the `code_files` arguments), and I can then `roxygenize`

```
> roxygenize("rlandscape", roxygen.dir = "rlandscape")
Updating collate directive in  /Users/Gregor/Dropbox/rlandscape/rlandscape/DESCRIPTION 
Updating namespace directives
Writing plot.landscape.Rd
Writing rland.Rd
Writing rland.gui.Rd
Writing makePoints.Rd
Writing rCluster.Rd
Writing rlandscape-package.Rd
Writing rlandscape.Rd
```

which seems to run successfully, but the DESCRIPTION file has the "Collate" field appended, but is otherwise unchanged from what `package.skeleton` created. Why isn't the rest of the description file updated?

Comment: One other thing. With **roxygen2**, for documentation blocks which aren't followed by code, I believe the recommendation is put a `NULL` (where you would've put a call to `roxygen()` if using the older **roxygen** package).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**roxygen2** is working just as intended, but I experienced the same confusion when I first used it to document a package.  The important bit to understand is that there are a couple of different package-describing files in the mix.

- When the roxygen markup in `rlandscape-package.R` is processed, it produces a file `rlandscape-package.Rd` in the man directory of your source package. This in turn produces the documentation you see when you type `?rlandscape` or `?"rlandscape-package"`.
- The `DESCRIPTION` file in the top directory of your source tree is a completely separate beast. Although it happens to produce a help file that you can see (via `help(package="rlandscape")`), it has many other more important roles in directing package production. The **only** way that it is touched/affected by **roxygen2** is that the `collate_roclet()` function (executed when you `roxygenize()` your package) will perform merges with the Collate field in a pre-existing `DESCRIPTION` file (as describe on p 10 of [this pdf](http://roxygen.org/useR/roxygen-part-1.pdf)).

The main take home message is that even when using roxygen2, if you want to make changes to your `DESCRIPTION` file, you'll need to do it by directly editing it.

Comment: Almost 2 years later, it'd be worth adding that the `devtools` package now provides functions like `create_description` for automatically creating description files.

Comment: As 2019 and version 2.2.1, there is no function `create_description`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And I believe the reason for that is to `push` the changes after `commit` ing from the Version Control under `Tools`. I guess you need to commit first, set your credentials then try to `push` the package using r console `usethis::use_github(protocol = "https")`, and if you created already a repo delete it and try this again. You can also check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79s3z0gIuFU&t=98s) 14th minute to see how `DESCRIPTION` updates.