# why roxygen2 does not automatically update "Imports" in DESCRIPTION file?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am trying to follow closely @hadley's [book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) to learn best practices in writing R packages. And I was thrilled to read these lines about the [philosophy](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/intro.html) of the book:

> anything that can be automated, should be automated. Do as little as
>   possible by hand. Do as much as possible with functions.

So when I was reading about dependencies and the (sort of) confusing differences between import directives in the NAMESPACE file and the "Imports:" field in the DESCRIPTION file, I was hoping that `roxygen2` would automatically handle both of them. [After all](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html)

> Every package mentioned in NAMESPACE must also be present in the
>   Imports or Depends fields.

I was hoping that `roxygen2` would take every @import in my functions and make sure it is included in the DESCRIPTION file. But it does not do that automatically.

So I either have to add it manually to the DESCRIPTION file or almost manually using `devtools::use_package`.

Looking around for an answer, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597993/does-roxygen2-automatically-write-namespace-directives-for-imports-packages) in SO, where @hadley confirms in the comments that

> Currently, the namespace roclet will modify NAMESPACE but not
>   DESCRIPTION

and other posts (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538573/roxygen2-not-fully-updating-description-file) or [here](http://v)) where `collate_roclet` is discussed, but "[This only matters if your code has side-effects; most commonly because you’re using S4](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html)".

I wonder:

- the reason that DESCRIPTION is not automatically updated (sort of contradicting the aforementioned philosophy, which is presumably shared by `roxygen2`) and
- If someone has already crafted a way to do it

Answer (score 3):

I have written a little R package for that task:

https://github.com/markusdumke/pkghelper

It scans the R Code and NAMESPACE for packages in use and adds them to the `Imports` section.

Answer (score 2):

The `namespace_roclet` edits the `NAMESPACE` file based on the tags added in the script before the function. As there are three types of dependencies (`Depends`, `Imports`, and `Suggests`), a similar method as used by the `namespace_roclet` would require three different tags (notice `Imports` should be a different one, to differentiate it from the packages to attach in `NAMESPACE`).

If you are willing to take a semi-automated process, you could identify the packages you have used and add the missing ones to `DESCRIPTION`, in the adequate sections.

```
library(reinstallr)

package.dir <- getwd()
base_path   <- normalizePath(package.dir)
files       <- list.files(file.path(base_path, "R"), full.names = TRUE)
packages    <- unique(reinstallr:::scan_for_packages(files)$package)

packages
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the two bullets you wonder about at the bottom:

- Updates to the DESCRIPTION file could be further automated with additional roclets, however already >4 years ago such a pull request was deferred:
  https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/pull/76
- I have to assume that the guys would indeed rather have you use the `devtools` package for updating the DESCRIPTION file, instead of adding this to `roxygen2`. So in that sense, `devtools` would be the first *available* choice