# Install dependencies of custom package

Tags: r, package, repository

I have developed a local package that depends on others available on CRAN (as an example, `pool`). Therefore, when I attempt to install the package using the standard

```
install.packages("/path/to/package",
                 repos = NULL,
                 type = "source")
```

I get an error because the dependencies aren't installed. `install.packages` has an argument `dependencies` which by default would try to install those dependencies. However, as stated by the man page (and commented in the linked question below), `repos = NULL` means the dependencies are ignored.

To get around that, I used package `miniCRAN` to create a repo containing my package, hoping I could do a `repos = c("myRepo", getOption("repos"))` to get it to work.

Now I can install my package using

```
install.packages("package",
                 repos = c("/path/to/repo", getOptions("repos"),
                 type = "source")
```

But only if I've already installed `pool`. If not, I still get an error because it can't find the dependencies.

So I called `miniCRAN::addPackage("pool")`, which adds that package and its many dependencies to my repo, and they all appear if I call `miniCRAN::pkgAvail()`.

However, if I attempt to install my package again, I still get a `there is no package called 'pool'` error.

Interestingly, if I try to install `pool` itself from the repo, it works.

```
install.packages("pool",
                 repos = "/path/to/repo",
                 type = "source")
install.packages("package",
                 repos = "/path/to/repo",
                 type = "source")
```

Obviously, however, this kind of beats the point of adding `pool` to the repo: I might just as well have installed it from CRAN.

So what's going on here, and is this really the only way to install local packages ***and*** their CRAN dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

The problem was a misunderstanding on my part regarding `roxygen`, which I've been using for my documentation. I assumed it handled the `Imports:` section of the DESCRIPTION file, which it doesn't ([(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9538573/2175231), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37193520/2175231)). So while the NAMESPACE file has all the necessary `importFrom(pool, ...)` calls, `pool` wasn't actually on my DESCRIPTION.

After fixing that oversight, using `remote::install_local("path/to/pkg")` (or `devtools::install()`) ([(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5805049/2175231)) worked: it installed my package and pulled its dependencies from CRAN.